# How can I autowire a specific implementation of an interface by its bean name in Spring

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I have classes which implements MyInterface and their names are for example:
`MyClassA`, `MyClassB` etc.

How can I get the instance of the class by it's bean name? Something like:

```
context.getBean("myClassA")
context.getBean("myClassB")
```

Can I do it without configuring beans in the XML?
I want to use annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers), e.g:

```
@Component
@Qualifier("classA")
public MyInterface ClassA {
     return new ClassA();
}

@Component
@Qualifier("classB")
public MyInterface ClassB {
     return new ClassB();
}
```

and use it like:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("classA")
    private MyInterface classA;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several options here. The easiest one would be using field names as a component name using `@Autowire`:

```
@Component("testClassA") // It is possible to omit explicit bean name declaration here since Spring will use a class name starting from lower case letter as a bean name by default. So just `@Component` should be sufficient here and below.
public TestClassA implements MyInterface {

}

@Component("testClassB")
public TestClassB implements MyInterface {

}

/*
 * Note that field names are the same as the component names.
 */
@Component
public class TestClassWithDependencies {
    @Autowired
    private MyInterface testClassA;

    @Autowired
    private MyInterface testClassB;
}
```

Another option is to use [qualifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers):

```
@Component
@Qualifier("testClassA")
public TestClassA implements MyInterface {

}

@Component
@Qualifier("testClassB")
public TestClassB implements MyInterface {

}

@Component
public class TestClassWithDependencies {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testClassA")
    private MyInterface testClassA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testClassB")
    private MyInterface testClassB;
}
```

You could even create your own meta-annotations when you need to use the same qualifiers over and over again:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier("testClassA")
public @interface TestClassACustomQualifier {
    String value();
}

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier("testClassB")
public @interface TestClassBCustomQualifier {
    String value();
}

@Component
public class TestClassWithDependencies {
    @Autowired
    @TestClassACustomQualifier
    private MyInterface testClassA;

    @Autowired
    @TestClassBCustomQualifier
    private MyInterface testClassB;
}
```

Much prettier, isn't it? One more option is to use **[@Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-resource-annotation)** from JSR-250 specification. As pointed out by @hovanessyan it's more JavaEE style of doing things, but still, I think it's a viable approach used on many projects:

```
@Component("testClassA")
public TestClassA implements MyInterface {

}

@Component("testClassB")
public TestClassB implements MyInterface {

}
@Component
public class TestClassWithDependencies {
    @Resource(name="testClassA")
    private MyInterface testClassA;

    @Resource(name="testClassB")
    private MyInterface testClassB;
}
```

More information you can get on https://www.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/, where discussed different approaches with tests added.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Resource is more in the lines of JEE, as it's part of JSR-250.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I have updated my answer and included this information

Answer (score 0):

I think if above options don't suffice then `factory implementation` is one way to get instance on the fly -

```
@Component
public TestClassA implements MyInterface {

}

@Component
public TestClassB implements MyInterface {

}
```

define you factory this way -

```
public class MyInterfaceFactory extends AbstractFactoryBean<MyInterface> {

    private String filter;
    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return MyInterface.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected MyInterface createInstance() throws Exception {
        MyInterface myInterface;
        switch (filter)
        {
            case "1":
                myInterface = new TestClassA();
                break;
            case "2":
                myInterface = new TestClassB();
                break;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such type.");
        }

        return myInterface;
    }
}

and then your bean config -

@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myInterface")
    public MyInterfaceFactory myInterfaceFactory() {
        MyInterfaceFactory factory = new MyInterfaceFactory();
        factory.setFilter("7070");
        return factory;
    }
}
```